# Split (parts of) image into several smaller (same size) pieces automatically

Tags: image-editing

Suppose I have an image with a table containing several rows, like the periodic table:

[image: the periodic table]

How can I split this into several images: one smaller one containing the `H     He` row, another for the `Li Be ... Ne` row, and so on?

It's OK if I have to specify the boundaries myself; the solution doesn't have to auto-detect them.

Manually selecting and cutting/copying in GIMP is not an option; I have way too many rows to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick, specifically the convert command with the crop option, should be able to help you. Check out the docs at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop

Note this line:

> If the x and y offsets are omitted, a
>   set of tiles of the specified
>   geometry, covering the entire input
>   image, is generated.

I think you might have to add more options to start at the correct offset.

Comment: I ended up writing a perl script to print out a sequence of crop commands with an increasing y offset.